# API для адресов

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Когда я ввожу адрес на яндекс картах, яндекс мне подсказывает Город, улицу, номер дома и прочее, как на dadata.ru
При этом он это делает для всех стран.
Но я не нащёл в API такой возможности для формирования подсказок ввода адресов.
Представляет ли яндекс подобное, и если да как именно этим воспользоваться и где почитать об этом?

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1-dev/ref/reference/suggest-docpage/

Comment: или даже тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView-docpage/

Comment: @Alexey Ten, Благодарю, нащёл https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest
Странно что Яндекс не позиционирует свой сервис как сервис адресов.

Comment: Есть еще [HTTP-геокодер](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/?from=mapsapi) и [HTTP-поиск по организациям](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/?from=mapsapi).
Напомню, что по [пользовательскому соглашению](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) любые данные, которые вы получите из саджеста или этих апи должны быть отображены на карте Яндекса (п. 3).

Comment: @flapenguin Благодарю! Да там много идиотских и невыполнимых условий. :-(
Но главное, на сколько я понял, получить можно только полный не компактный адрес, отформатированный яндексом, нельзя задать желаемый формат адреса, и нельзя выделить его родителей и свойства родителя (Страну, код страны, регион, код региона, сокращение региона, населённый пункт, сокращение населённого пункта). В таком виде он мне малополезен разве что получить от яндекса и сразу запихнуть его в dadata, получив то что мне требуется.